# Setting the width of a MEDIUM_RECTANGLE admob ad to fit screen width

Tags: java, android, admob, ads

I am currently trying to display my ads in a listview with a custom adapter so every 10 items an ad is displayed in the listview just like one of the items but I am having trouble making the ad fit screen width because I am using :

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/listAdview"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
ads:adSize="MEDIUM_RECTANGLE"
ads:adUnitId="@string/videoListAd"
>
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

so I already have the adsize set to MEDIUM_RECTANGLE to get 300x250 ads what I would like to do is stretch the ad to make it fit screen width is this possible ? if so how can it be done ? I was taking a look at google's developers site at : [Google Api Adsize](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/AdSize.html#public-method-summary) and came accross the FULL_WIDTH constant but could'nt really figure out how to make use of it.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

FULL_WIDTH is not intended for this purpose.

Displaying AdMob ads in a ListView is a discouraged implementation because it can lead to violations of AdMob policy (multiple ads on a single screen, loading of ads that are not displayed). You should instead place the banner outside the scrolling content region at the top or bottom of your UI.

See this link for guidance on the best ways to display banners:

https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6275345

**EDIT:** While displaying AdMob banners in a ListView is still a discouraged implementation, using a ListView to display ads in the new [Native Express](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/native-express) format is not, so that's now an option.

Comment: I have been very carefull with admobs ad display policy, no more than one ad is ever displayed on the screen and the ad is paused once its out of the users view , what I did was create a seperate layout for the ad and have my custom adapters getView method return this view which is only inflated once on the oncreate method of the activity so I am not violating any admob policy I think...

Comment: Is this answer still correct? Admob no longer has a limit on # of ads per screen. Plus, there is a (much older) post on the admob blog explaining how to put ads in a List View :

http://google-ads-developer.blogspot.com/2012/03/embedding-admob-ads-within-listview-on.html

As well as a (much more recent) codelab :

https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/admob-native-advanced-feed-android/index.html#0